# Excel index and match function with wild card string

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying match a string from spreadsheet 2 with string with wild card in between two cell values from spreasheet 1 and then return value from column C from Spreadsheet 1 into column B into spreadsheet 2 when matched.

**Spreadsheet 1**

```
A               B                C 
Jonathan        Smith            1234
Sarah           Jones            1235
```

**Spreadsheet 2**

```
A                             B 
Jonathan Harry Smith          Return value from column C from Spreadsheet 1 - expected to be 1234     
Sarah Jones                   Return value from column C from Spreadsheet 1 - expected to be 1235
```

Formula I tried is

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH('Spreadsheet 1'A1&"*"&'Spreadsheet 1'B1,'Spreadsheet 1'C:C,0))
```

The formula doesn't seem to work as it's not returning the correct value from column C from spreadsheet 1, it returns a value for a different person.
Where I have a gone wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula appears to be backwards as it would return the name on Sheet2 rather than the value in Column C of Sheet1.  It is also matching based on the order of Sheet1 rather than the order of Sheet2.  Had the sheets been in a different order, the formula would fail.

I'm not entirely sure the excel wildcard works in the way you need it to.  I would suggest parsing out the first and last names of Column A in sheet2 and match them with Columns A and B in Sheet1.  This will work as long as there are either 1 or 2 spaces in Column A of Sheet2.  Try this formula in Cell B2 of Sheet2:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(IFERROR(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(" ",A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)+1)),RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(" ",A2))),IF(Sheet1!A:A=LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1),Sheet1!B:B),0),1)
```

This formula works without entering it as an array formula, which surprises me.  To be safe, I would treat it as an array formula by executing it with CTRL + Shift + Enter.

Comment: The name in sheet2 column can have first name middle names and surname, what I was trying was for sheet1, there's usually first name in column a and surname in column b, so as long as sheet2.column a start with sheet1.column A and ends with sheet1.column B, then it's a match and returns value into sheet2.